# How to use FixedU128?

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain, floating-point-math, convert, math

I'm fetching floating value in offchain worker though `lite-json`.

Json data:

```json
{
"price": 0.5
}
```

Here is the implementation to fetch the price:

```rust
let price_str = match obj.clone() {
                JsonValue::Object(obj_data) => {
                    let (_, v) = obj_data.into_iter().find(|(k, _)| k.iter().copied().eq("price".chars()))?;
                    match v {
                        JsonValue::Number(val) => val,
                        _ => return None,
                    }
                },
                _ => return None,
            };
let bits = price_str.integer as u128 * 10u128.pow(price_str.exponent as u32) + u128::from(price_str.fraction);
log::info!("bits: {}", bits);
// Adjust the denominator based on the desired scale
let fixed_value = FixedU128::saturating_from_rational(bits, 10u128.pow(price_str.fraction_length as u32));

            log::info!("value of integer is {}", fixed_value);
```

I'm getting these logs:

```
2023-12-09 22:25:03.084  INFO      offchain-worker pallet_template: bits: 5    
2023-12-09 22:25:03.084  INFO      offchain-worker pallet_template: value of integer is 500000000000000000
```

I should get fixed_value to be `0.5` but getting `500000000000000000`.

I have tried almost all the methods to convert this but either i get `0` or `500000000000000000`.

How to fetch this price effectively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `FixedU128` is not a floating point type. It represents floating point numbers using `u128` type with 18 digits of precision. This means that the last 18 digits of any number are taken to be the fractional part and the rest are taken to be the integer part.

This way, we can represent `1.23` as `1_230_000_000_000_000_000`. Where `230_000_000_000_000_000` is the fractional part and `1` is the integer part.

So `500000000000000000` is the correct value. You can see that by printing it using the debug format

```
log::info!("value of integer is {:?}", fixed_value);
```